# laravel 5.6 socialite auth by facebook email is null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I use laravel 5.6 and laravel/socialite: "^3.2.0" for auth by Facebook but while login to facebook user email is null (user facebook account has email)

my code for auth :

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

        dd($user);
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        return redirect($this->redirectTo);
    }

public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
        if ($authUser) {
            return $authUser;
        }

        return User::create([
            'name'     => $user->name,
            'email'    => $user->email,
            'provider' => $provider,
            'provider_id' => $user->id
        ]);
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zYEI.png
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is no error in your code. There are some additional things you need to enable to solve this problem.

you have to change the **email permission** from "**standard** access" to "**advanced** access".

To enable this permission, you need to enter the  in the below URL

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app-id>/app-review/permissions/
```

after changing the permission, you will start receiving the email in the payload.

Answer (score 2):

There is no error in your code.

---

Facebook users register using a **Mobile number** instead of Email address. This means that Facebook doesn't have an email address for that specific user. So this will be giving you back **NULL**

Please check this under the section ([Email](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email))

Comment: i used my account for test and my account has email address

Comment: @saman There is no error in your code, don't know whether your any other part of code any error, please share if you have an idea which part have you code wrong Then I can help you out this problem...check your migration have you see it like this `$table->string('email')->unique();`

Comment: i check it and email is unique
my question is that, event though account has an email address, so why email is null ?!

Comment: i checked by facebook test user and it is ok

Comment: Mobile number isn't required, at least where I am. I registered with my email.